# how to automatically remove org-emphasis markers, i.e. org-deemphasize?

Tags: org-emphasis, wrap-region

There is a function `org-emphasize`, which wraps selected text in `org-emphasis` markers. (Though I personally use a similar function called [wrap-region](https://github.com/rejeep/wrap-region.el).)

Is there a function `org-deemphasize` (or analogously, `unwrap-string-at-point`) that will remove `org-emphasis` markers before and after point? (Without my having to manually select the exact region?)

It should refer to `org-emphasis-alist` For example, my customized org-emphasis alist looks like this:

```
(("*" bold)
("/" italic)
("_" underline)
("=" org-code verbatim)
("~" flyspell-incorrect)
("+"
(:strike-through t)))
```

Comment: `(org-emphasize ? )` does almost what you ask - you'd just need to figure out how to set the region around the currently-emphasized text before you call it.

Comment: OP did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @SFbay007 Try this.